# RegEx for parsing chemical formulas

Tags: objective-c, regex

I need a way to separate a chemical formula into its components. The result should look like
this:

```
   Ag3PO4 -> [Ag3, P, O4]
      H2O -> [H2, O]
   CH3OOH -> [C, H3, O, O, H]
Ca3(PO4)2 -> [Ca3, (PO4)2]
```

I don't know regex syntax, but I know I need something like this

[An optional parenthesis][A capital letter][0 or more lowercase letters][0 or more numbers][An optional parenthesis][0 or more numbers]

This worked

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[A-Z][a-z]*\\d*|\\([^)]+\\)\\d*"
                              options:0
                              error:nil];
NSArray *tests = [[NSArray alloc ] initWithObjects:@"Ca3(PO4)2", @"HCl", @"CaCO3", @"ZnCl2", @"C7H6O2", @"BaSO4", nil];
for (NSString *testString in tests)
{
    NSLog(@"Testing: %@", testString);
    NSArray *myArray = [regex matchesInString:testString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [testString length])] ;
    NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[myArray count]];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in myArray) {
        NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:0];
        [matches addObject:[testString substringWithRange:matchRange]];
        NSLog(@"%@", [matches lastObject]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure chemical formulas are a regular language. You might be able to take a crack at it, but it would likely not be perfect.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Take a look at my above attempt, as long as I could get something like that working, then I would be cool with it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`(PO4)2` really sits aside from all.

Let's start from simple, match items without parenthesis:

```
[A-Z][a-z]?\d*
```

Using regex above we can successfully parse `Ag3PO4`, `H2O`, `CH3OOH`.

Then we need to somehow add expression for group. Group by itself can be matched using:

```
\(.*?\)\d+
```

So we add `or` condition:

```
[A-Z][a-z]?\d*|\(.*?\)\d+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xL9bK3)

Which works for given cases. But may be you have some more samples.

**Note:** It will have problems with nested parenthesis. Ex. `Co3(Fe(CN)6)2`

If you want to handle that case, you can use the following regex:

```
[A-Z][a-z]?\d*|(?<!\([^)]*)\(.*\)\d+(?![^(]*\))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

For Objective-C you can use the expression without lookarounds:

```
[A-Z][a-z]?\d*|\([^()]*(?:\(.*\))?[^()]*\)\d+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qM3vH8)

Or regex with repetitions (I don't know such formulas, but in case if there is anything like `A(B(CD)3E(FG)4)5` - multiple parenthesis blocks inside one.

```
[A-Z][a-z]?\d*|\((?:[^()]*(?:\(.*\))?[^()]*)+\)\d+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zG4kV8)

Comment: Thanks a bunch man, and to all the other posters for the quick help. This really helps me understand regexes, and they all get the job done!

Comment: I don't run into the double parentheses very often, but as it stands, they are an issue because `Co3(Fe(CN)6)2` produces `[Co3, (Fe(CN)6]`.

Comment: @doctordoder It misses `2`, should be `(Fe(CN)6)2`. I added regex to handle such cases.

Comment: I ran into some trouble with your last edit. I think it's just an Objective-C thing, though. For example, each \ needs to be written as \\ because they are `NSString` objects. This is what I tried, which left me with no matches for each test: https://gist.github.com/MichaelSnowden/e5badcffeb7c4300d067

Comment: @doctordoder My fault, Objective-C doesn't support `*` quantifier in lookbehinds.

Comment: @doctordoder I added one more expression. Can you test against your code?

Comment: You should probably beware of greediness when using `\(.*\)`. Thorough answer for one level deep nested patterns !

Comment: @Robin I was looking through internet for chemical formulas with more nested levels and didn't find any. Can you provide the sample?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: I wasn't criticizing, on the contrary. The regex should fit to its data, and there's is no way to perfectly match nested patterns without recursion. The greediness thing will see `(Ag(PO)2)2H2O(Ag(NO2)2)2` as one match instead of 3, though.

Comment: @Robin I believe OP wants single match for that :)

Comment: Off topic, but how did you generate those funky visualisations of the regex patterns?

Answer (score 4):

When you encounter a parenthesis group, you don't want to parse what's inside, right?

If there are no nested parenthesis groups you can simply use

```
[A-Z][a-z]*\d*|\([^)]+\)\d*
```

`\d` is a shorcut for `[0-9]`, `[^)]` means anything but a parenthesis.

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/mA3iB9).

Answer (score 3):

This should just about work:

```
/(\(?)([A-Z])([a-z]*)([0-9]*)(\))?([0-9]*)/g
```

Comment: Why all the capture groups?

Comment: I imagined the OP wanted each part as a separate match.

Answer (score 2):

this pattern should work depending on you RegEx engine
`([A-Z][a-z]*\d*)|(\((?:[^()]+|(?R))*\)\d*)` with `gm` option
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oH7eS3)

Answer (score 0):

Better to limit the set of chars to valid chemical names. In simple form:

^((Ac|Ag|Al|Am|Ar|As|At|Au|B|Ba|Be|Bh|Bi|Bk|Br|C|Ca|Cd|Ce|Cf|Cl|Cm|Co|Cr|Cs|Cu|Ds|Db|Dy|Er|Es|Eu|F|Fe|Fm|Fr|Ga|Gd|Ge|H|He|Hf|Hg|Ho|Hs|I|In|Ir|K|Kr|La|Li|Lr|Lu|Md|Mg|Mn|Mo|Mt|N|Na|Nb|Nd|Ne|Ni|No|Np|O|Os|P|Pa|Pb|Pd|Pm|Po|Pr|Pt|Pu|Ra|Rb|Re|Rf|Rg|Rh|Rn|Ru|S|Sb|Sc|Se|Sg|Si|Sm|Sn|Sr|Ta|Tb|Tc|Te|Th|Ti|Tl|Tm|U|V|W|Xe|Y|Yb|Zn|Zr)\d*)+$

This doesn't deal with the parenthesized groups.

This we worked out during the San Diego Python Users Group meeting.