# Python split not the expected result

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to cut a string into pieces in Python with the following code:

`re.split("[A-Z][a-z]?[0-9]*","CO2")`

I expect some result like this:

```
["C","O2"]
```

however I get:

```
['','','']
```

Comment: Overall, you might rather use `re.match`, and look at what `groups` you get out. `split` is really best used when you have certain delimiters you want to discard. [Full regex documentation is here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)

Comment: recommendation: [regex-for-parsing-chemical-formulas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602175/regex-for-parsing-chemical-formulas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no capturing groups in your re, the things you split on are not part of the result. What you're getting is the empty string before the 'C', the empty string between 'C' and 'O2' and the empty string after 'O2'.

If you use

```
re.split("([A-Z][a-z]?[0-9]*)","CO2")
```

you'll get

```
['', 'C', '', 'O2', '']
```

One dirty approach would be to use

```
filter(None, re.split("([A-Z][a-z]?[0-9]*)","CO2"))
```

to remove elements that are not truthy (in this case, empty strings).

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to split**

Use look arounds like this:

```
(?<=[A-Z\d])(?=[A-Z])
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/eV0rY5/1)

---

**Else**

To simply match (without split):

```
[A-Z][a-z]?\d*
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/eV0rY5/4)

---

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this one:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = re.findall(r"^([A-Z][a-z]?)([A-Z][0-9]*)$","CO2")
>>> list(x[0])
['C', 'O2']
```