# Split string by uppercase words/chars and numerics

Tags: arrays, swift, string, contains

I have the string like this - "H2SO4liH2", i need to split this string by uppercase elements and numerics. At the out i need to get array like this
"H2", "S", "O4", "Li", "H2" or
"H", "2", "S", "O", "4", "Li", "H", "2"

Comment: You can use Regex for that with patterns given there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602175/regex-for-parsing-chemical-formulas and then separate. Also, you meant `"H2SO4LiH2" (with an upper "L"), no?

Comment: yes L an upper, my fault. it's seem's me need to split elements in brackets (LiH)2

Comment: i got it. right pattern is "[A-Z][a-z]?\\d*|\\([^()]*(?:\\(.*\\))?[^()]*\\)\\d+"

Comment: In Cocoa you need indeed to escape the escape character: "\" => "\\" to be interpreted as a "\" escape Regex pattern.

Comment: yes, i got it, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses the pattern provided in toheedNiaz's answer but in a Swift context:

```
let string = "H2SO4LiH2"

let pattern = "[A-Z][^A-Z]*"
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
    for match in matches {
        let range = Range(match.range, in: string)!
        print(string[range])
    }
} catch {
    print("Regex Error:", error)
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't mind accept the answer.

Comment: you should use string utf16view count instead of count (utf8)

Comment: @LeoDabus As far as I know the periodic table does not contain any non-ascii characters 

Comment: I know that in this case it won’t make a difference but people might use it for something else