# How to split string by numerical and letters

Tags: swift, string, contains

String is "H2" or "He2".
How to split this string to get result like "H", "2" or "He" , "2"

I try use string.components separatedBy .decimalDigits, but as the result lose the digits.

```
let intStr = elem.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits).joined(separator: ":")
```

Comment: What is the difference to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539956/split-string-by-uppercase-words-chars-and-numerics)?

Comment: i can use RegEx, but, i think there is a way easier. I need to first divide the string into elements, and then each element with a digit, divided by an element and a digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is `(NS)Scanner`:

```
let string = "He2"
let scanner = Scanner(string: string)
var element : NSString?
var ordinal = 0
if scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits, into: &element),
    scanner.scanInt(&ordinal) {
    let intStr = "\(element!):\(ordinal)"
}
```

Comment: `(NS)Scanner` is extremely useful, but seems to be somewhat unknown/underrated. In my experience it is also very fast. (On the other hand, `components(separatedBy:)` is overrated/overused in my opinion :-)

Comment: @MartinR I agree. `components(separatedBy:)` is useless in this (dynamic) case anyway.