# How to iterate over a dictionary and operate with its elements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

I have this dictionary, where the keys represent atom types and the values represent the atomic masses:

```
mass = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.01, 'O': 15.9994, 'N': 14.0067, 'S': 31.972071,
        'P': 30.973762}
```

what I want to do is to create a function that given a molecule, for instance `('H2-N-C6-H4-C-O-2H')`, iterates over the `mass` dictionary and calculates the atomic mass on the given molecule. The value of the mass must be multiplied by the number that comes right after the atom type: `H2 = H.value * 2`

I know that firstly I must isolate the keys of the given molecules, for this I could use `string.split('-')`. Then, I think I could use and `if` block to stablish a condition to accomplish if the key of the given molecule is in the dictionary. But later I'm lost about how I should proceed to find the mass for each key of the dictionary.

The expected result should be something like:

```
mass_counter('H2-N15-P3')

out[0] 39351.14
```

How could I do this?

EDIT:

This is what I've tried so far

```
# Atomic masses
mass = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.01, 'O': 15.9994, 'N': 14.0067, 'S': 31.972071, 
        'P': 30.973762}

def calculate_atomic_mass(molecule):
    """
    Calculate the atomic mass of a given molecule
    """
    mass = 0.0
    mol = molecule.split('-')

    for key in mass:
        if key in mol:
            atom = key

    return mass

print calculate_atomic_mass('H2-O')
print calculate_atomic_mass('H2-S-O4')
print calculate_atomic_mass('C2-H5-O-H')
print calculate_atomic_mass('H2-N-C6-H4-C-O-2H')
```

Comment: Can you show what you already tried?

Comment: What is the `2` doing in *front* of `H` by the way?

Comment: i'm gonna edit my question with the code i have till now. But it's not complete,because i can't figure out how to continue. give me a minute

Comment: it multiplies the H value for 2, or any other number for example H3 = H[value] * 3

Comment: Yes, but here we see `2H` at the end of your first example?

Comment: He was talking about the last item in `'H2-N-C6-H4-C-O-2H'`, but that is most likely a typo.

Comment: The output in your example looks very wrong, by about a factor of 100

Comment: Allright, excuse me, it was a typo, now it's fixed. Sorry

Comment: @Feodoran i did it manually, multiplying the mass values by the number of atoms, if you do the math, that's the result.

Comment: 'H2-N15-P3': `1*2 + 14*15 + 31*3 = 305`

Comment: @Feodoran `(1.007825*2)*(14.0067*15)*(30.973762*3) = 39351.149253846655`

Comment: Why would you **multiply** the masses?

Comment: Instead of checking for each possible element in your "molecule" and then having to figure out how many of such atoms there are, and worry about multiply occurrences, do it the other way around: split by `-`, get element and number, get mass by simply indexing the dictionary with the element as a key `masses[element]`.

Comment: @Miguel2488: you here seem to *multiply* the masses of the individual atoms, but as far as I know the mass of a molecule is in essence the sum of the mass of its atoms.

Comment: @Feodoran  and Willem Van Onsem Excuse me, you are totally right, i'm sorry i got my head a little troubled and i don't know what i'm doing anymore. Excuse me you are both right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given all components have the shape `Aa123`, It might be easier here to identify parts with a regex, for example:

```
import re
srch = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d*)')
mass = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.01, 'O': 15.9994, 'N': 14.0067, 'S': 31.972071, 'P': 30.973762}

def calculate_atomic_mass(molecule):
    return sum(mass[a[1]]*int(a[2] or '1') for a in srch.finditer(molecule))
```

Here our [regular expression [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) thus captures a sequence of `[A-Z-a-z]`s, and a (possibly empty) sequence of digits (`\d*`), these are the first and second capture group respectively, and thus can be obtained for a match with `a[1]` and `a[2]`.

this then yields:

```
>>> print(calculate_atomic_mass('H2-O'))
18.01505
>>> print(calculate_atomic_mass('H2-S-O4'))
97.985321
>>> print(calculate_atomic_mass('C2-H5-O-H'))
46.06635
>>> print(calculate_atomic_mass('H2-N-C6-H4-C-O-2H'))
121.130875
>>> print(calculate_atomic_mass('H2-N15-P3'))
305.037436
```

We thus take the sum of the `mass[..]` of the first capture group (the name of the atom) times the number at the end, and we use `'1'` in case no such number can be found.

Or we can first split the data, and then look for a atom part and a number part:

```
import re
srch = re.compile(r'^([A-Za-z]+)(\d*)$')

def calculate_atomic_mass(molecule):
    """
    Calculate the atomic mass of a given molecule
    """
    result = 0.0
    mol = molecule.split('-')
    if atm in mol:
        c = srch.find(atm)
        result += result[c[1]] * int(c[2] or '1')
    return result
```

Comment: Hi Willem, thank you very much for your answer. I don't know much about `regex`, please could provide some extra explanation about what is the `re.compile` part doing? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer without regex:

```
import string
# Atomic masses
masses = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.01, 'O': 15.9994, 'N': 14.0067, 'S': 31.972071, 
        'P': 30.973762}

def calculate_atomic_mass(molecule):
    """
    Calculate the atomic mass of a given molecule
    """
    mass = 0.0
    for key in molecule.split('-'):
        # check if any number is available
        if not key[-1] in string.digits:
            el, n = key, 1
        # check length of element label (1 or 2)
        elif key[1] in string.digits:
            el, n = key[:1], int(key[1:])
        else:
            el, n = key[:2], int(key[2:])
        mass += masses[el]*n
    return mass

print calculate_atomic_mass('H2-O')
print calculate_atomic_mass('H2-S-O4')
print calculate_atomic_mass('C2-H5-O-H')
print calculate_atomic_mass('H2-N-C6-H4-C-O-H2')
```

Comment: Thank you Feodoran, it's a nice way to do it. It's good to learn about different ways of doing this :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it. You don't really need to iterate over the dictionary. Instead you need to iterate over the atom(s) in the molecule and look things up (randomly) in the dictionary.

Here's an example of doing that which assumes that there'll never be more that 10 atoms of any kind making up the molecule and the each element's name is only one letter long.

```
# Atomic masses.
MASSES = {'H': 1.007825, 'C': 12.01, 'O': 15.9994, 'N': 14.0067, 'S': 31.972071,
          'P': 30.973762}

def calculate_atomic_mass(molecule):
    """ Calculate the atomic mass of a given molecule. """
    mass = 0.0
    for atom in molecule.split('-'):
        if len(atom) == 1:
            mass += MASSES[atom]
        else:
            atom, count = atom[0], atom[1]
            mass += MASSES[atom] * int(count)

    return mass

print calculate_atomic_mass('H2-O')               # -> 18.01505
print calculate_atomic_mass('H2-S-O4')            # -> 97.985321
print calculate_atomic_mass('C2-H5-O-H')          # -> 46.06635
print calculate_atomic_mass('H2-N-C6-H4-C-O-H2')  # -> 122.1387
```

Comment: Your are also assuming that all element labels are of length 1. This is true for the here given examples, but not in general.

Comment: @Feodoran: True, but the basic idea still holds. To handle the most general case would require more sophisticated parsing (probably via a regex). I only included the minimum that would solve the problem posted (and address the titular question about how to iterate over a dictionary).

Comment: Hi Martineau, it's ok, I get the idea ;)

Comment: Miguel: Thanks...and good to hear. The question [RegEx for parsing chemical formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602175/regex-for-parsing-chemical-formulas) should help parsing them with regular expressions (which are an alternative to what's in @Feodoran's answer).